# Java unparseable date when using substrings

Tags: java, substring, simpledateformat

Here's the problem I am currently having I am writing a program that is getting info from a webpage table and the date for the first row is eg. "September 21, 2011".

The subsequent rows then have the format of "September 28, 2011 (2011-09-28)".

I am trying to substring the date but I keep getting Unparseable date: "September 21, 2011"
whenever I do substring the string. If I don't substring the first date will work but the subsequent will crash and if I do even substring the first string it also crashes.

```
String date = tableData.get(airDate).text();
int index = date.length();
if(date.contains("(")){
   index = date.indexOf((int)'(') - 1;
}
date = date.substring(0, index);
Date simpleDate = formatter.parse(date);
```

My program is completely stuffed and I don't know why. Now I can no longer substring a string let along get the date to format right :(

Comment: How do you create your formatter ?

Comment: I would use `date = date.trim()` after the substring operation.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. It was similar to something that happened during an internship. This HTML library I was using had the same namespace as the Simple Date Format and String manipulation in Java. The simple fix was to create a facade to get the information from the HTML I required then manipulate is as a standard string

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("September 28, 2011 (2011-09-28");
    System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
Wed Sep 28 00:00:00 EEST 2011
```

Comment: doesn't work tired that already still get unparsable date exception :(

Comment: Simple date: Wed Sep 21 00:00:00 EST 2011
Season: 1, Episode: 1, Air Date: September 21, 2011
Season Location: 0 Air Date Location: 4
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "September 28, 2011 (2011-09-28)"
Terminal ouput

Comment: @user2078282 Well, but I tested it before posting, see my update it's just from my Eclispe console

Comment: I know that may work for you but When I tried it. It still fails I don't know why